# How can i give a file name with a number but to count++ the number after all files got the names?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i mean is first time i'm downloading 40 files to the hard disk.
At the first time i want to add to each file name a number: 000000.png
For example: First___000000.png
Then: Two____000000.png
Then Three____000000.png

Now all the files will be download to each own directory with a diffrenet name but same number. For example First___000000.png will be in directory First. and Two___000000.png in directory Two and so on. This part is working fine my problem is that after 15 minutes i'm downloading the files again this time i want to increase the numbers by 1. So now it should be like: First___000001.png and Two___000001.png and Three___000001.png and again it will be saved/downloading to directory First and Two and Three and each directory there will be two files: First___000000.png and First___000001.png and so on.

```
public FileStream LocalDirectorySettings(FileInfo file)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(LocalDirectory, file.Name);
                string fileName = Path.Combine(path, file.Name + "---" + countFilesNames++.ToString("D6") + ".png");

                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                return new FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

The problem now is that i will have in directory Ten a file name: Ten___000010.png instead Ten___000000.png

I could set countFilesNames to reset it to 0 after each download but then when i will download the files again how will i change it to be 1 countFilesNames=1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I do understand what you want, but at this moment your code is not fault-tolerant. Consider what will happen if your client crashes mid-way and only download 20 files out of 40. You counter `countFilesNames` has now gone, and all files downloaded before will be re-written with some fresh copies, but files not reached yet by second round will remain in their folders. Here comes a mess.

There is no other way of doing this without scanning already downloaded files in folders, i.e. `First`, `Two`, ..., `Ten`, etc.

Only after scanning directory structure you can identify what files are already there and restore counters to correct values.

I hope you know how to write all related code.

Comment: If i understand it correct, then i need to use something like GetFiles each time running the program and check against a List of the files names so if all the files with the number 000000 downloaded then now start a new count of 000001 but if only some files downloaded of the 000000 ? Should i try to download the missing files or just to the next 000001 round ? Or maybe i should write all the files names downloaded to a text file and read the text file lines back each time and decide according to it somehow ?

Comment: I could write to a text file the date and time of the last download round then check each time i'm running the program if 15 minutes passed then give the next round files names with 000001 since the files content on the site will never be the same each 15 minutes it will be something else. I could also give each file name a date and time and check against it in the next download for example First___01-02-2017-16-00-00 or something in this logics.

Comment: You can use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` to obtain a list of files, including their timestamps and sizes. See this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

for one-time action ne could simply use a constant suffix:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(path, file.Name + "---000000.png");
```

since multiple download are possible in each folder, check file count in the folder and use it as a part of a name for a new file:

```
var fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path).Length;
string fileName = Path.Combine(path, file.Name + "---" + fileCount.ToString("D6") + ".png");
```